# Hybris Readonly UserGroup

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, access-rights, usergroups

I need to set up a user group which should have access to everything like the admingroup but with readonly rightsg. I know that there is a way to set the access rights for single types, but is there any method which sets the readonly right to all? Also I need to know if there is a type which allows login rights to specific cockpits. The problem is that some users are allowed to access to productcockpit but not into cmscockpit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please see the script below, this script enables read only rights for the product cockpit. Please change the same for other cockpits

```
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# Import Access Rights for Product Cockpit
# 

$defaultPassword=1234


INSERT_UPDATE UserGroup;UID[unique=true];groups(uid)[mode=append]
;myproductmanagergroup;cockpitgroup,employeegroup

INSERT_UPDATE Employee;UID[unique=true];password[default=$defaultPassword];description;name;groups(uid);sessionLanguage(isocode);sessionCurrency(isocode)
;myproductmanager;;Product manager;My Product Manager; myproductmanagergroup;en;ZAR

UPDATE CatalogVersion;catalog(id)[unique=true];version[unique=true];writePrincipals(uid);
;apparelProductCatalog;Online;myproductmanagergroup,myproductmanager; 
;apparelProductCatalog;Staged;myproductmanagergroup,myproductmanager; 


$START_USERRIGHTS;;;;;;;;;
Type;UID;MemberOfGroups;Password;Target;read;change;create;remove;change_perm
UserGroup;myproductmanagergroup;cockpitgroup;;;;;;;

# Access Rights for Products & Catalog;;;;;;;;;
;;;;Product;+;-;-;-;-;
$END_USERRIGHTS;;;;;
```

Comment: If I understand you right there is no smarter way to set everything to Readonly. My consideration is that I have over 1300 targets and I don't know which ich have to set and which not.

Comment: I haven't tried it but maybe you can try to use beanshell in the impex to iterate over all item types?

Comment: @LukasFrey - What do you mean by 'smarter way'? What is the use case yo u're after?

Answer (score 0):

@Vikrant I was looking for a way to set readonly on every single Item so that this group can't change anything. My final solution is to set readonly right to the Target Item like this:

```
$START_USERRIGHTS; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ;

Type      ; UID                        ; MemberOfGroups ; Password ; Target                ; read ; change ; create ; remove ; change_perm
UserGroup ; readonlygroup              ;                ;          ;                       ;      ;        ;        ;        ;
          ;                            ;                ;          ; Item                  ; +    ; -      ; -      ; -
          ;                            ;                ;          ; ProductReference      ; +    ; -      ; -      ; -

$END_USERRIGHTS; ; ; ; ;
```

Comment: Okay! I see you made an intelligent use of the impex script. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, the solution is to create user group, then give it user rights for Item - this will apply for all types. And update catalogs with readPrincipals.

```
INSERT_UPDATE UserGroup; UID[unique = true]      ; locname[lang = en]           ; description                               ; backOfficeLoginDisabled[default = false]

; backofficereadonlygroup ; "Backoffice Read Only Group" ; "User has read only access to the Backoffice" ;


$START_USERRIGHTS;;;;;;;;;
Type;UID;MemberOfGroups;Password;Target;read;change;create;remove;change_perm
UserGroup;backofficereadonlygroup;;;;;;;;

;;;;Item;+;-;-;-;-;

$END_USERRIGHTS;;;;;


UPDATE CatalogVersion;catalog(id)[unique=true];version[unique=true];readPrincipals(uid);
;Default;Online;backofficereadonlygroup;
;Default;Staged;backofficereadonlygroup;
```